# Spring java to jsp - multi table select

Tags: java, sql, spring, jsp

i was looking all over the place and few books and nothing simple found. I have a sql like:

```
select
a.id,b.name,b.points,d.name,d.second_name,c.id
from my_courses a
left join course b on a.idcourse=b.id
left join student c on a.idstudent=c.id
left join human d on c.idhuman=d.id
```

and i would like to execute(in java) and display(in jsp in table) few other random sql without having DAO,POJO and other classes. Is it possible some simple solution like writing a sql, executing the sql, get maybe array or something  filled with sql result and send it to jsp to display in table? Thanks a lot.
I am using java,spring,jsp in spring tool suite.

Comment: For now it seems the thing i was looking for is like 'SqlRowSet foo = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sql);'.

Answer (score 0):

Before you read the following answer please make clear:

- You should basically **NEVER EVER** mix presentation-layer/data-access-layer together. You will end up in chaos/tears.

But I found a solution you can find in detail here:

[data-acces in presentation layer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm)

And here is a code example from that source:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST"
 user="root"  password="pass123"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
   <th>Emp ID</th>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Last Name</th>
   <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
   <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Please note that I do not recommend that. It's just bad! very bad!